# How do you shorten the errorcode shown on the console while programming

Tags: cmd, error-handling, command-prompt, stderr

I have the problem, when I make a bigger mistake while programming, I get errors that each take up 100 lines. The useful errorcode is in the very top, while the rest looks like a copy/paste of the same useless text going something like:

```
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\8.2.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from 9.2.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\8.2.0\include\c++\ostream:682:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Ostream, class _Tp> typename std::enable_if<std::__and_<std::__not
_<std::is_lvalue_reference<_Tp> >, std::__is_convertible_to_basic_ostream<_Ostream>, std::__is_insertable<typename std::__is_convertible_to_basic_ostream<_Tp>
::__ostream_type, const _Tp&, void> >::value, typename std::__is_convertible_to_basic_ostream<_Tp>::__ostream_type>::type std::operator<<(_Ostream&&, const _T
p&)'
```

What can I do to make the [command-prompt](/questions/tagged/command-prompt) window omit this part? I know what the problem is, but I don't want the same line of text spam my entire [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) window all the time.

Comment: My advice is don't make mistakes, and certainly not big ones. Take a step back, where do you think the error is coming from? It's coming from the command/executable you're using. This is not a [tag:cmd] or [tag:command-prompt] issue. I would suggest that you change your question tags to reflect the actual command/executable and perhaps use the [tag:error-handling] and /or [tag:stderr] tags too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the error code using this batch file:

```
@echo off
pushd %~dp0
The command generated the long error 1>nul 2>errors.txt
set /p errorcode=<errors.txt
echo %errorcode%
del /f /q errors.txt
popd
goto :eof
```

Run it from the cmd and you will get the error code.

Comment: Well I suppose that will print only `In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\8.2.0\include\c++\iostream:39,` to the console, although I doubt from that, that it will be of any use to the OP. I would also suggest that you take a look at the Command Prompt output from `del /?`, because I see no need for either of those options you're using.